# OpenGL - Object local rotation

Tags: math, opengl, matrix, rotation

I am trying to make something like - lets call it flight simulator using modern OpenGL. I am trying to use yaw, pitch and roll to rotate my plane object. But it seems object rotates around global coordinate system (I mean if my object faces vector (0,0,1) roll operation works like it should but if i turn it to face for example (1,0,0) it behaves like pitch)

my transformation matrix is calculated like this:

```
  transformation_matrix = perspective_projection_matrix *
                        camera_rotation_matrix *
                        camera_translation_matrix *
                        translation_matrix *
                        rotation_matrix *
                        scale_matrix;
```

Rotation matrix is

```
rotation_matrix = rotation_z * rotation_y * rotation_x;
```

I tried to add local rotation matrix before translation one but it looks even worse (object now flies around some point in space facing always default)

What should I do to rotate object like typical plane with yaw, pitch and roll in local coordinates system?

EDIT

<s>I also noticed that rotation is performed in global coordinate system with camera position as (0,0,0)</s> 
Not the case, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane's orientation will ultimately be the concatenation of many discrete rotations around different axes. This is not the same as simply summing the individual rotations. They are not independent.

For example, if you pitch up 90 degrees, roll 90 degrees, and then pitch down 90 degrees, the resulting orientation will *not* be a roll of 90 degrees, but instead a *yaw* of 90 degrees.

Instead, keep a persistant matrix which represents the orientation of your plane, and then apply roll, pitch, and yaw rotations to it as appropriate.

Comment: I dont know if i understand well. I already keep all 3 rotation angles and calculate rotation matrix each frame (as shown above). My yaw, pitch and roll operations are only modyfing this angles. And it works well but in global coordinate system as i said.

Comment: And the problem is with how you are interpreting/accumulating those angles, and not with the transformation.

Comment: So yaw, pitch and roll rotation isn't just simple x_angle_rotation * y_angle_rotation * z_angle_rotation matrix? Need to rethink this

Comment: No. A single rotation around one of those axes is fine, but when you do a sequence of them, the result is no longer as simple as summing the individual rotations, no matter what order you apply them. The easiest solution is to accumulate the transforms.

Comment: @JasonD So are you saying that instead of maintaining x, y, and z rotation values and calculating the rotation matrix fresh on each frame, you need to just keep applying rotations to the same matrix sequentially?

Comment: I solved this problem with Quaternions. Thanks for your help.